# Flex 4.5 - Global Variable across all views?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mobile, mxml, global

How do you define a global variable that is accessible across all views on Flex mobile / Flex 4.5/4.6

--

(Edited for clarification)

Is it still necessary to have to use a separate global class?

(additional) There is a new PersistanceManager in Flex 4.5, is there something like a GlobalObjectsManager that can be used to just set/get stuff in memory?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825115/flex-sharing-data-between-different-components

Comment: There are a few scattered threads, some based on earlier versions of Flex where [Bindable] is needed. It would be nice to get an updated Flex 4.5/4.6 version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017277/global-variable-in-flex

Comment: Why not use a separate Global class as mentioned there? Seems like the best way to go...

Comment: I guess my question is - is it still necessary to have to use a separate global class? There is a new PersistanceManager in Flex 4.5, is there something like a GlobalObjectsManager that can be used to just set/get stuff in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like comment given by pradeek declare a separate Global class

```
 package xyz
{

public class Global
{
    public function Global()
    {   } 
//Declare all Global variables here
}
}
```

You can import that class in your application

```
import xyz.Global;
```

Comment: Are there any considerations that should be given to package name? The other examples specify just `package{}`, without naming the package - but i notice you have named your package. Which is preferable/why?

Comment: @ina `package{}` is default package but if you create some other package is preferable refer this link [http://www.coderanch.com/t/104469/vc/why-defult-package-discouraged-eclipse]

Comment: Also, is it necessary to have a constructor function if you have a class just to declare global variables? (I notice you have a constructor above.)

Comment: Constructor is not necessary. when you create new action script class by default it creates constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

PersistanceManager is primarily for storing data in case your app is interrupted and closed by the OS. Read [this article](http://macromedia.com/devnet/flex/articles/web-mobile-reference-apps.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_2) for a good overview of how to organize your app.

Comment: okay, but there is not actually a global variables manager, like the persistence manager, in Flex 4.5?